# How to get all the letters starting with a

Tags: python

I want to get all the words starting with a or A in a string printed.

But, this just prints all the elements. What should i do to solve it?

I have made the following:

```
string1= input("Enter a string: ")

words= string1.split()

for word in words:
    if(word[0]=='a' or 'A'):
        print(word)
```

This prints all the elements instead of just the letters starting with a or A.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value - `... or 'A'` is **always true**.

Answer (score 1):

```
string1= input("Enter a string: ")

words= string1.split()

for word in words:
    if(word[0]=='a' or word[0] == 'A'):
        print(word)
```

You did `word[0] == 'a' or 'A'`, which always evaluate to true.
You can even use list comprehension like this:

```
a_words = [word for word in words if word[0] =='a' or word[0] == 'A']
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
string1= input("Enter a string: ")

words= string1.split()

for word in words:
    if(word[0] in ['a', 'A']):
        print(word)
```

or with an even shorter if statement:

```
    if(word[0] in 'aA'):
```

Answer (score 0):

Your test is incorrectly written. Right now it looks like this:

```
if(word[0]=='a' or 'A'):
    print(word)
```

But since 'A' isn't null, the loop is basically:

```
if(word[0]=='a' or True):
    print(word)
```

And it will always enter, because `anything or True` is True.

What you actually want is to test both against `a` and `A`, like this:

```
if(word[0]=='a' or word[0]=='A'):
    print(word)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, I fixed it

```
string1= input("Enter a string: ")

words= string1.split()

for word in words:
    if(word[0]=='a' or word[0]=='A'):
        print(word)
```

When you write like

```
if(word[0]=='a' or 'A'):
```

python evaluates `word[0]=='a'` separately and `'A'` separately where `'A'` is implicitly converted to true. Hence your condition is always true.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
>>> string= input("Enter a string: ")
Enter a string: a world of an Apple
>>> string
'a world of an Apple'
>>> words_starts_with_a_or_A = [word for word in string.split() if word.lower().startswith('a')]
>>> words_starts_with_a_or_A
['a', 'an', 'Apple']
```

Comment: Use casefold instead of lower.

Answer (score 0):

Using the operator `in`:

```
s = input("Enter a string: ")

words = s.split()

for word in words:
    if word[0] in 'Aa':
        print(word)
```

Using the function `any()` with a generator comprehension and the method `startswith()`:

```
s = input("Enter a string: ")

words = s.split()

for word in words:
    if any(word.startswith(i) for i in 'Aa'):
        print(word)
```

or with a comparison operator:

```
s = input("Enter a string: ")

words = s.split()

for word in words:
    if any(word[0] == i for i in 'Aa'):
        print(word)
```